# select from string field , separated SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

I have table1 that has field contains value separated with ','

```
 name           value
--------------------------
    test           1,2
    flower         3
    car            4,2
    dog            2
```

I want select command that finds rows contain specific value in this column

`string @value = 2`

`select * from table1 where ?`

```
 name           value
--------------------------
    test           1,2
    car            4,2
    dog            2
```

Comment: Thes best solution for this is changing your DB structure. Never store multiple values in one column!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE
      str LIKE '%,' + @input + ',%' OR
      str LIKE @input + ',%' OR
      str LIKE '%,' +@input OR 
      str = @input
```

you need to have few conditions if you using LIKE operator because of the position of input field and the commas

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f137a/4)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Here is working demo **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40f1a/1)**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE CHARINDEX(',2,', ','+value+',') > 0;
```